# Using multi profiles in Android browsers?

Tags: browser

I want to have multi profiles in Android browsers. I mean, tabs that can open the same site with different credentials like many browsers on Windows.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Firefox for Android has support for opening private tabs which might help you?

Comment: @davidgo in this case the different tabs will be open the same site with the same credentials. For example, the same twitter account in two tabs.

Comment: I think we may be talking past each other. From a server POV a private browsing tab should be totally disassociated from other tabs - ie you can use the same or different credentials in it and the server will see the browsing sessions as unrelated. Also, your comment seems to contradict ypur post with respect of diffetent vs same credentials. You may eant to clear that up.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found one, but my solution is...

- I have many browsers installed and I use Firefox, Chrome, Brave, and DuckDuckGo for different purposes. There are many more choices to select from.

  I have Brave installed as the default browser and use it for general purposes.
- Another option is to install [Parallel Space](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lbe.parallel.intl), this will let you run a clone of another app.  If you really want to use the two copies of the same browser, then you can run one under PS.

I have no affiliations with any of the browsers or Parallel Space.